# How to get the actual Google search result count for a given keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

How to get the actual Google search result count for a given keyword?

Google lies about its search result counts, it gives a big number in the first page (from a few hundred thousands to several millions), and that number does not change until the very last page, which is usually numbered around twenty, then it tells you the truth that it has only found about two hundred results...

I want to know the exact number of search results, the number displayed at the last page, the search queries are enclosed in double quotation marks because I need the parameters to be exact.

For example, searching `"liberty, equality, fraternity"` boasts 264,000 results:

[image]

But it reached the last page at page 17 and tells you it only has found 159 results:

[image]

As you can see from the images, I have already wrote a script that does exactly this, but it is extremely inefficient:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from string import ascii_letters, digits

Firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
valid = digits + ascii_letters

def url_encode(s):
    query = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in valid:
            query += c
        elif c == ' ':
            query += '+'
        else:
            query += ''.join(f'%{b:02X}' for b in c.encode('utf8'))
    return query


BASE_SEARCH = 'https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22{}%22&gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&start={}&num=100'
def search_result_count(s):
    query = url_encode(s)
    page = 0
    Firefox.get(BASE_SEARCH.format(query, page))
    count = int(Firefox.find_element(by='id', value='result-stats').text.split()[1].replace(',', ''))
    init_count = count
    while count == init_count:
        page += 1
        Firefox.get(BASE_SEARCH.format(query, page*100))
        segments = Firefox.find_element(by='id', value='result-stats').text.split()
        index = 3
        if segments[index] == 'about':
            index += 1
        count = int(segments[index].replace(',', ''))
    return count
```

The idea is to get the count on the first page, then use a while loop to iteratively get the count on the next page, the number does not change until the very last page, so compare the current count with the first count and break out of the while loop if they are not equal.

But this method is very time consuming:

```
In [3]: %time search_result_count('liberty equality fraternity')
Wall time: 34.3 s
Out[3]: 159
```

And I have to solve a reCAPTCHA every other use...

So what is a better method to do this?

---

Slightly better method, but still slow in my network.

---

This method is still bad because I use a VPN, and every time I run the code, Google will through a reCAPTCHA at me, saying something along the lines: "Our system has detected unusual traffic originating from your network...", and the code will throw `NoSuchElementException`, after solving the reCAPTCHA I can run exactly the same line of code for once, it will get results, but after that if I try to query again I have to solve another reCAPTCHA...

And after four or five times of successful queries in one selenium section, any further queries will result in 403 forbidden...

---

I have tried Google Custom Search JSON API but it is not what I want, it can only return 10 results per page and it still lies about the count of results until the very last page.

And as stated by Google:

> start  integer (uint32 format)
>
> The index of the first result to return. The default number of results
> per page is 10, so &start=11 would start at the top of the second page
> of results. Note: The JSON API will never return more than 100
> results, even if more than 100 documents match the query, so setting
> the sum of start + num to a number greater than 100 will produce an
> error. Also note that the maximum value for num is 10.

[source](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list)

Google custom search engine API will only return a maximum number of 100 results no matter what, and the usual number of results Google fetched is around 200, so the API is useless in my use case.

I have tried this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from string import ascii_letters, digits


options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
Chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
Chrome.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
Chrome.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/101.0', })
```

But I still got stopped by reCAPTCHA.

I have tried many more methods, all those methods posted here which I found through Google, none of them works.

But I don't need to solve reCAPTCHAs if I use a normal browser and manually search these things using the address I found:

[https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22{}%22&gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&start={}&num=100&filter=0](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22%7B%7D%22&gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&start=%7B%7D&num=100&filter=0)

But I need to search thousands of keywords, I am not actually interested in whatever results Google search returns, only the count of results, I am trying to sort various topics based on their importance, and the more results Google returns the more important the topic is, simple as that.

So is there a working way to completely avoid reCAPTCHA while using selenium in 2022 or is there another API provider that uses the exact syntax Google uses, returns exactly what the address points to in normal browsers, for free?

Comment: I reach the last page on 2 page. As i can see you have added **num=100** param. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22liberty,+equality,+fraternity%22&num=100. With 2 request you get this last number no?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply see the available pages and with the help of WebDriverWait, click them until you reach the last one. Then with

**driver.find_element().text**

extract the number of results
like this:

```
import time
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

#agree the terms and conditions
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'L2AGLb'))
    ).click()


# send query
query = "liberty, equality, fraternity"
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@class="gLFyf gsfi"]')
search_bar.send_keys(query)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# wait to result been loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h3[@class="LC20lb MBeuO DKV0Md"]'))
    )

# loop over page results
while True:
    try:
        # reach last page
        WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a//span[contains(text(), "Next")]'))
        )
        # get page available
        pages = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('SJajHc NVbCr').length")
        goto_page = pages - 1 if pages == 10 else pages - 2 
        driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByClassName('SJajHc NVbCr')[{goto_page}].click();")
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print("you reach the last page")
        break
    
#get number of results
result = driver.find_element(By.ID, "result-stats")
print(result.text)

driver.close()
```

In this way no one reCAPTCHA comes out. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for an answer for 3 long hours

Assuming you have an html with a linked js.

1. Go to [https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?supportedpurview=project][1] and create a proyect and in credentials part generate your api key and too yo need another number
2. Put this script scr on your html
   //THIS SCRIPT NEEDS TO HAVE THIS IN THE HTML

and this in the js part
function scrapImageByName(keyword) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "jsonp",
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1",
data: {
key: "AIzaSyCzb6SI_JRrp6xLLYV617Ary6n59h36ros",
cx: "004286675445984025592:ypgpkv9fjd4",
filter: "1",
searchType: "image",
//imgSize: "small",
q: keyword
}
}).done(function (data) {
//alert("Success");
console.log(data);
var googleResults = data.items;

```
    $(".result li").remove();
    //$('#result').isotope('destroy');

    var imageURL = googleResults[0].image.thumbnailLink;
    console.log('IMAGE URL', imageURL)

});
```

}

3. This function and call it with argument like scrapByName('Banana')

```js
function scrapImageByName(keyword) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1",
        data: {
          key: "AIzaSyCzb6SI_JRrp6xLLYV617Ary6n59h36ros",
          cx: "004286675445984025592:ypgpkv9fjd4",
          filter: "1",
          searchType: "image",
          //imgSize: "small",
          q: keyword
        }
      }).done(function (data) {
        //alert("Success");
        console.log(data);
        var googleResults = data.items;
    
        $(".result li").remove();
        //$('#result').isotope('destroy');
    
        var imageURL = googleResults[0].image.thumbnailLink;
        console.log('IMAGE URL', imageURL)
    
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Open the console and type scrapImageByName('Banana') then you will get imageurl and then you can create a promise and async funcion but this is another thing</p>
</body>

<script>
function scrapImageByName(keyword) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1",
        data: {
          key: "AIzaSyCzb6SI_JRrp6xLLYV617Ary6n59h36ros",
          cx: "004286675445984025592:ypgpkv9fjd4",
          filter: "1",
          searchType: "image",
          //imgSize: "small",
          q: keyword
        }
      }).done(function (data) {
        //alert("Success");
        console.log(data);
        var googleResults = data.items;
    
        $(".result li").remove();
        //$('#result').isotope('destroy');
    
        var imageURL = googleResults[0].image.thumbnailLink;
        console.log('IMAGE URL', imageURL)
    
    });
}
</script>

</html>l
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).